Does Dan Willard demonstrate that classical logics with the Law of the Excluded Middle versus those with Double Negation Elimination are distinct?
Context:
Dan Willard's 2020 review paper of his work on Self-Verifying Theories/Self-Justifying Axiom Systems (SJAS) is titled "How the Law of Excluded Middle Pertains to the Second Incompleteness Theorem and its Boundary-Case Exceptions" [0]. In it, he claims that by disallowing the Law of the Excluded Middle (LEM) as a axiom schema, SJAS of sufficiently weak expressivity, that use the method of analytic tableaux (MAT) as their deduction method, evade Goedel's Second Incompleteness Theorem (G2). That is, SJAS so constructed are both in fact consistent, and can prove their own consistency. This holds even should the LEM be proven to hold as a theorem for arbitrary formulae. If the LEM is allowed as a an axiom schema, then SJAS, otherwise identically constructed, cross a threshold that causes G2 to apply to them.
To quote from the introduction:

Our self-justifying axiom systems are different, however, because their built-in
self-referencing “I am consistent” axioms have their meanings change, fundamentally,
when their self-referencing concept of “I” involves promoting a schema of theorems
verifying the Law of Excluded Middle into formal explicitly declared logical axioms.
This effect is counterintuitive because similar distinctions exist almost nowhere
else in Logic. Thus some confusion, that has surrounded our prior work, can be
clarified when one realizes that an interaction between the self-referencing concept
of “I” with the Law of Excluded Middle causes the Second Incompleteness Theorem
to become activated precisely when the Law of Excluded Middle is promoted into becoming a schema of logical axioms.


The intuitive reason for this unusual effect is that the transforming of derived
theorems into logical axioms can shorten proofs under the Fitting-Smullyan semantic tableau technology. In the particular context where §3’s formalism uses selfreferencing “I am consistent” axioms and views multiplication as a 3-way relationship, these conditions will be sufficient for enacting the full power of the Second Incompleteness Theorem.

Question:
The method of analytic tableaux cited in the Appendix is classical, insofar as it allows the rule of Double Negation Elimination (DNE). DNE and LEM each mutually imply the other. However, here Willard appears to demonstrate that a classical MAT with DNE is distinct (cannot prove the same theorems, namely the consistency of an SJAS) from a classical MAT with LEM.
Does this in turn demonstrate a difference in the kinds of classical logic?
That is, would it be correct to classify, on the basis of the "SJAS test", a subdivision between classical logics with DNE as axiomatic, versus classical logics with LEM as axiomatic?
Equivalently, is the logic of an SJAS classical, intuitionistic, or some other, hybrid category?
[0] https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01057

I didn't read the paper, but it's considering particularly weak systems which are very peculiar. There is not one single "classical logic", but virtually almost all systems that are usually referred to by this expression (classical first-order/second-order/higher-order logic) are equivalent with LEM or DNE.

Yes, "classical" is an adjective applied to various formal systems, and is generally 1) compatible with interchangeably admitting LEM or DNE as rules 2) incompatible with formal systems described as "intuitionistic" or "constructive", which exclude both LEM and DNE. I am asking, in essence, whether Willard's SJAS demonstrates that there is another adjective, that of "semi-classical", or "LEM-classical" vs "DNE-classical".
